# Android Google Maps - Wrong endpoint coordinates after changing the origin

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a navigation app where it redirects to Google maps with the Latitude and longitude coordinates. Users have been reporting recently that the endpoint in Google maps is wrong despite it being right in the app, after changing the origin location.

After doing some troubleshooting the bug seems to be in Google Maps, but I cannot find any other resources or issues that confirm this bug. I am looking for others to confirm this bug.

Replicate the bug in Google maps on an Android device as follows:

1. Open Google Maps on an Android Device (I am running an S10 running Android Version 12)
2. Search for Lat/Lng coordinates such as **52.66, -114.00**, these coordinates are North of Gull Lake
3. Tap directions, The correct directions will be shown to the coordinates entered from your location.
4. Tap "Your Location" to change the origin location. Enter some nearby town, I used **Edmonton**.
5. New directions will show up with the original location as correct, but the endpoint is now very wrong, In this test it put the endpoint north or Rimby,about 20 km away from the original endpoint.

Please let me know if you can replicate this bug on your Android device.

EDIT: [Here is a video of the issue](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/QBGb-8tLDck)

Comment: Did you find any fix ?

Comment: did you find.any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I test it on Xiaomi Mi 9T Pro, Android 11.

This is what I get,

[image]

**and after tap "directions"**

[image]

It seems to be the normal behaviour from here

Answer (score 0):

Some of our customers also reported very similar problems last days:
Drivers are getting wrong position in Google Maps.

I could reproduce the issue on my phone, with almost equal steps as you said:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ysCDrNvP3g4
(ok, I started an target change, but cancelled it)

It seems like even lat/lon is geocoded, lat/lon is used for target position.
Then some conditions deletes lat/lon -> Now geocoded text is the target -> not exactly the same.

Comment: I thought it had to do with the text also, maybe defaulting back to a county or something, so I tried making the label also the lat, lng coordinates. That didn't help.